# Copy-Item from UNC path located in a different domain

Tags: powershell

I have been given a task to install a software(msi) across servers (2008,2012,2016) that are scattered across several domains. The trick is to copy the installation, configuration files from a UNC that is located in a different domain to each server locally. Different PowerShell version behave in different ways.
Initially on Server 2016s I tried **New-PSSession** and **-FromSession** switch to establish a connection to the server (successfully) that had the UNC path and copy like so:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Username "<domain_with_unc_share>\$($env:username)"
$unc_server_session = New-PSSession -ComputerName unc_server -Credential $creds
Copy-Item "d:\share\*.*" -Destination "c:\temp\" -FromSession $unc_server_session -Recurse
```

**-FromSession** switch was introduced with PS5 and works well with Sevrer 2016 but anything lower and this fails. This clearly does not work for Windows 2008/2012.

I then tried to use just a UNC in Copy-Item like so:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Username "<domain_with_unc_share>\$($env:username)"
Copy-Item "\\unc_server\share\*.*" -Destination "c:\temp\" -Credential $creds -Recurse
```

This gives me an error that **-Credential** switch cannot be used with **Copy-Item** and defers to using **New-PSDrive**

```
Copy-Item : Cannot retrieve the dynamic parameters for the cmdlet. The FileSystem provider supports credentials only
on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying credentials.
At line:1 char:1
+ Copy-Item "\\unc_server\share\ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetDynamicParametersException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I then tried the following:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Username "<domain_with_unc_share>\$($env:username)"
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\unc_server\share" -Credential $creds
Copy-Item "Y:\*.*" -Destination "c:\temp\" -Recurse
```

Still not happy, it tells me that my UNC path does not exist:

```
New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\\unc_server\share"
either does not exist, or it is not a folder.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name "Y" -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\unc_server\share ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (Y:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

I am a loss as to how to appease the PowerShell God so it works across PS3,4,5.
Any suggestions?

Comment: In file explorer, can you reach `\\unc_server\share` ? Have you tried using the IP address instead of the unc_server name?

Comment: Heya Theo. I can definitely access the share via explorer. That is the bit I do not get. I use the same credentials to initiate Session, works for Session, does not work for New-PSDrive.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the -Persist switch indicate you are mapping a network drive:

```
$creds = Get-Credential -Username "<domain_with_unc_share>\$($env:username)" 
New-PSDrive -Name Y -PSProvider filesystem -Root "\\unc_server\share" -Credential $creds -Persist
 Copy-Item "Y:\*.*" -Destination "c:\temp\" -Recurse
```

Comment: Thanks Wasif, even though this is for a temporary copy session?

Comment: With -Persist switch i now get the error: New-PSDrive : The specified network password is not correct. I had to double check my credentials were correct because I am able to authenticate if I open an explorer windows to browser to the share

Comment: Check the username and password again.

Comment: I triple checked. The password is correct. The only thing I can think of is my password contains special characters but that should not be an issue since I am using Get-Credential to collect password. Ideas?